# Selecting distinct values from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have my JSON as follows

```
{"DATA": [{"id":11,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":12,"name":"javascript","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":13,"name":"jquery","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":14,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":15,"name":"jquery","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":16,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
{"id":20,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63}],"COUNT":"120"}
```

Is there any good method to find out the `distinct name` from this JSON

Result `javascript,jquery,ajax`

I can do this using following methode

```
var arr=[''];
var j=0;
for (var i = 0; i < varjson.DATA.length; i++) {
  if($.inArray(varjson.DATA[i]["name"],arr)<0){
      arr[j]=varjson.DATA[i]["name"];
      j++;
  }
}
```

Is there any `better method` which gave me better performance?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I would use one Object and one Array, if you want to save some cycle:

```
var lookup = {};
var items = json.DATA;
var result = [];

for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
  var name = item.name;

  if (!(name in lookup)) {
    lookup[name] = 1;
    result.push(name);
  }
}
```

In this way you're basically avoiding the `indexOf` / `inArray` call, and you will get an Array that can be iterate quicker than iterating object's properties – also because in the second case you need to check `hasOwnProperty`.

Of course if you're fine with just an Object you can avoid the check and the `result.push` at all, and in case get the array using `Object.keys(lookup)`, but it won't be faster than that.

Comment: it takes almost same time as mine. Here is the comparison http://jsfiddle.net/MsYGJ/1/   .Among these sberry method gave better performance.

Comment: Could you please post the jsfiddle with also my method as comparison? Because in my test this approach is definitely faster than your original one, and it seems faster than sberry one too – but I'd like to double check. It could be that I'm missing something, or you have implemented in a different way.

Comment: Well, you have to remove the alert at line 354. Without it on my Firefox / Chrome / Safari is almost instantaneous, compare to the other to approaches; as also my test shown.

Comment: @ZER0 +1 for the way you iterated through an array.

Comment: Not to be a Debbie Downer, but almost 5 years later this popped back up in my feed because of an upvote.  @ZERO the problem with your fiddle is that you perform your method exactly once, while my approach is iterated 100,000 times.  This is an updated version that shows my method is approx 3 times faster: http://jsfiddle.net/MsYGJ/113/.  Of course optimization in this sort of time scale is seldom needed.

Answer (score 23):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is great for this kind of thing. You can use [`_.countBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) to get the counts per `name`:

```
data = [{"id":11,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":12,"name":"javascript","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":13,"name":"jquery","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":14,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":15,"name":"jquery","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":16,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63},
        {"id":20,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63}]

_.countBy(data, function(data) { return data.name; });
```

Gives:

```
{ajax: 4, javascript: 1, jquery: 2}
```

For an array of the keys just use [`_.keys()`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)

```
_.keys(_.countBy(data, function(data) { return data.name; }));
```

Gives:

```
["ajax", "javascript", "jquery"]
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this countBy method selecting a pair of fields? For example, I would like to have the number of occurrences for each key / date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075039/counting-number-of-elements-with-desired-conditions-in-json/34075630#34075630 Thank you, @iiSeymour.

Answer (score 18):

Use Jquery Method unique.

```
var UniqueNames= $.unique(data.DATA.map(function (d) {return d.name;}));

alert($.unique(names));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/QCx4a/)

Comment: this having a problem. If the name is repeated more than twice in the result that name appears twice. eg :if ajax comes 3 times then result contain `2 ajax`

Comment: check jsfiddle it's not working as you say...I have put all name "ajax" and result showing only one Ajax.
Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/QCx4a/)

Comment: nop. please check here http://jsfiddle.net/MsYGJ/3/ . Also it takes more time than other methods

Answer (score 16):

This is a great spot for a reduce

```
var uniqueArray = o.DATA.reduce(function (a, d) {
       if (a.indexOf(d.name) === -1) {
         a.push(d.name);
       }
       return a;
    }, []);
```

Comment: it takes more time than sberry's method.

Comment: Yes there was no reason for the map in there. A single reduce could do it.


You should be aware that @sberry's solution does not check hasOwnProperty. Stray properties from the prototype could find their way in to your list.

Answer (score 11):

First we can just run `map()` function to get the new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the `varjson.DATA`.

```
varjson.DATA.map(({name})=>name))
```

After getting the array of `name` from the `varjson.DATA`. We can convert it into a set that will discard all duplicate entries of array and apply [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get a array of unique names:

```
[...new Set(varjson.DATA.map(({name})=>name))]
```

```js
const varjson = {
  "DATA": [{
      "id": 11,
      "name": "ajax",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "javascript",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "jquery",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "ajax",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "jquery",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "ajax",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "ajax",
      "subject": "OR",
      "mark": 63
    }
  ],
  "COUNT": "120"
}

console.log( [...new Set(varjson.DATA.map(({name})=>name))]);
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Comment: Thanks, this is the most update to date solution.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see here, when you have more values there is a better approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/MsYGJ/

```
temp = {}
// Store each of the elements in an object keyed of of the name field.  If there is a collision (the name already exists) then it is just replaced with the most recent one.
for (var i = 0; i < varjson.DATA.length; i++) {
    temp[varjson.DATA[i].name] = varjson.DATA[i];
}
// Reset the array in varjson
varjson.DATA = [];
// Push each of the values back into the array.
for (var o in temp) {
    varjson.DATA.push(temp[o]);
}
```

Here we are creating an object with the `name` as the key.  The value is simply the original object from the array.  Doing this, each replacement is O(1) and there is no need to check if it already exists.  You then pull each of the values out and repopulate the array.

**NOTE**
For smaller arrays, your approach is slightly faster.

**NOTE 2**
This will not preserve the original order.

Comment: +1. I have a `maximum of 100` rows , `normally 10` . So which method i can adopt? Or i need to implement both and see the difference

Comment: perfectly ok. your method will gave me better performance. Thank you sberry

Answer (score 2):

try this, MYJSON will be your json data.

```
var mytky=[];
mytky=DistinctRecords(MYJSON,"mykeyname");

function DistinctRecords(MYJSON,prop) {
  return MYJSON.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
 })
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't get an array of distinct key values (values of attribute "mykeyname"); I get an array with the right number of elements, and one for each distinct value of "mykeyname", but the mytky array holds entire objects, not just key values (e.g., objects like {"id":11,"name":"ajax","subject":"OR","mark":63} from the OP, not just elements like 11). Also am I right that this iterates N-squared times for N objects in MYJSON array? I think so: .filter() iterates over all elements, and for each iteration .map() does the same, right?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
var distinct_list 

  = data.DATA.map(function (d) {return d[x];}).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
```