# How to Get Distinct Values From Json Data without sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this type of JSON data

[image]

I have written the code to eliminate duplicate records in JQuery

```
function GetUniqueTablesCategory(Data) {
  var UniqueNames = $.unique(Data, function(d) {
    return d.TableName;
  });
  return UniqueNames;
}
```

But I am getting this error below, can anyone please help me out to eliminate this issue.

[image]

Comment: It throws an error because objects cannot be sorted. The `$.unique()` method is designed to be used with an array of DOMElements, see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Comment: Is this while running your code? It seems that you do not give an array as an argument. Did you convert the JSON into an array?

Comment: Rory McCrossan , how I will achieve this without using $.unique() method, can you please share me any link.

Comment: You need to write your own logic to replicate it, via loops.

Comment: I am going to write my own logic .   , thanks  .  once I done will add in post .

Answer (score 3):

You can write a one-liner using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from ES6

```
let uniqueNames = [...new Set(Data.map(d => d.TableName))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a simple loop :

```
function GetUniqueTablesCategory(Data) {
  var UniqueNames = [];
  Data.forEach(function(value) {
      if (UniqueNames.indexOf(value.TableName) === -1) {
          UniqueNames.push(value.TableName);
      }
  });

  return UniqueNames ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is acceptable, you can write your method like this:

```
function GetUniqueTablesCategory(data) {
  return _.uniq(_.map(data, function(d){return d.Name}));
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn7gnzun/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var lookup = {};
 var obj = [{'TableName': 'prop1','value5': 'prop3'},{ 'TableName': 'prop1','value5': 'prop3'}, {'TableName': 'prop3','value5': 'prop3'}];
 var array=[];
 for (var ob, i = 0; ob = obj[i++];) {
    var name = ob.TableName;

    if (!(name in lookup)) {
      lookup[name] = 1;
      array.push(name);
    }
  }

 alert(JSON.stringify(array));
 
 });//submit click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can find a similar thread here also.[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780508/selecting-distinct-values-from-a-json)