# Remove Duplicate objects from JSON Array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am receiving the below `json` object from service:

```
[{
    "EmployeeID": 8513,
    "EmployeeName": "Afridi,Masoom Khan",
    "EmployeeMailID": "Masoom.Afridi@COELAB.COM",
    "Vertical": "INFRA",
    "ProjectID": "000000000002105",
    "ProjectDescription": "ITH - Data Center Impl.",
    "PeriodEndDate": "19-JUN-16",
    "TimeSheetID": "0001612322",
    "CreationDate": "27-JUN-16",
    "SubmissionDate": "27-JUN-16",
    "TimeSheetStatus": "NA",
    "Approver": "MISHRA,BISWAJIT",
    "ApproverMailID": "biswajit.mishra@COELAB.COM"
}, {
    "EmployeeID": 8513,
    "EmployeeName": "Afridi,Masoom Khan",
    "EmployeeMailID": "Masoom.Afridi@COELAB.COM",
    "Vertical": "INFRA",
    "ProjectID": "000000000002105",
    "ProjectDescription": "ITH - Data Center Impl.",
    "PeriodEndDate": "26-JUN-16",
    "TimeSheetID": "0001612324",
    "CreationDate": "27-JUN-16",
    "SubmissionDate": "27-JUN-16",
    "TimeSheetStatus": "NA",
    "Approver": "MISHRA,BISWAJIT",
    "ApproverMailID": "biswajit.mishra@COELAB.COM"
}]
```

I would like to convert the given object into below `json` format:

```
[{
    "ProjectID": "000000000002105",
    "ProjectDescription": "ITH - Data Center Impl.",
    "Approver": "MISHRA,BISWAJIT",
    "ApproverMailID": "biswajit.mishra@COELAB.COM",
    "Employee": {
        "EmployeeID": 8513,
        "EmployeeName": "Afridi,Masoom Khan",
        "EmployeeMailID": "Masoom.Afridi@COELAB.COM",
        "Vertical": "INFRA",
        "TimeSheet": [{
            "PeriodEndDate": "26-JUN-16",
            "TimeSheetID": "0001612324",
            "CreationDate": "27-JUN-16",
            "SubmissionDate": "27-JUN-16",
            "TimeSheetStatus": "NA"
        }, {
            "PeriodEndDate": "19-JUN-16",
            "TimeSheetID": "0001612322",
            "CreationDate": "27-JUN-16",
            "SubmissionDate": "27-JUN-16",
            "TimeSheetStatus": "NA"
        }]
    }
}]
```

could you please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try? Btw. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780508/selecting-distinct-values-from-a-json

Comment: Create plnkr/fiddle for your question.